# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{-nx}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate the limit$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{-nx}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx$$

I used L'Hopital's Rule

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{-nx}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{-nx}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{-1}\frac{1/n}{\sin (1/n)}.\frac{-1}{n^2}}{-\frac{1}{2n\sqrt{n}}}=0$$

Is it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not differentiate the numerator correctly. For  a simpler proof use the inequality $\sin x \geq \frac 2 {\pi} x$ for $0 <x <\frac {\pi} 2$. You will see very easily that the limit is $0$.

[ $\int_0^{1/n}e^{-ny}dy=\frac {1-e^{-1}} n$].

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$0 \le \sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{-nx}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx \le \sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx.$$

By the mean value theorem there is $t_n \in (0,1/n)$ such that

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{x}{\sin x}= \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{t_n}{\sin t_n}.$$

Hence

$$0 \le \sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{-nx}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx \le \sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \frac{t_n}{\sin t_n}$$

This gives that the limit in question $=0.$

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geq 1$,
\begin{align*}
0 < \sqrt n \int_0^{1/n} {e^{ - nx} \frac{x}{{\sin x}}dx} & < \frac{1}{{\sin 1}}\sqrt n \int_0^{1/n} {e^{ - nx} dx} \\ & < \frac{1}{{\sin 1}}\sqrt n \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - nx} dx}  = \frac{1}{{\sin 1}}\frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}.
\end{align*}
Thus, by the squeeze theorem, the limit is $0$. A bit more interesting problem is
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } n\int_0^{1/n} {e^{ - nx} \frac{x}{{\sin x}}dx} .
$$

Comment: Will the limit be undefined if instead of $\sqrt{n}$ we have $n$ as you have mentioned

Comment: It will be $1-e^{-1}$.

Comment: What about $\sin 1$ in the denominator

Comment: What I gave here is an upper bound not a precise estimate. To obtain the limit I propose, you have to use more precise estimates, i.e., $\frac{x}{{\sin x}} = 1 + \mathcal{O}(x^2 )$ near $x=0$.